# Unable to make MySql connection with LoopBack

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, loopbackjs

I've been following the Loopback tutorial at https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Connect+your+API+to+a+data+source

As per the docs, I have the following **server/datasources.json**

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory"
  },
  "mysqlDs": {
    "name": "mysqlDs",
    "connector": "mysql",
    "host": "demo.strongloop.com",
    "port": 3306,
    "database": "demo",
    "username": "demo",
    "password": "L00pBack"
  }
}
```

My **server/model-config.json** has the following info

```
{
  ...
  "CoffeeShop": {
    "dataSource": "mysqlDs",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

And I've minimised the **server/boot/create_sample_model.js** to:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.dataSources.mysqlDs.automigrate('CoffeeShop', function(err) {
    console.log(err.message);   
  });
};
```

This outputs:

`Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3000
Browse your REST API at http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer
{ [Error: Query inactivity timeout]
  code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
  fatal: true,
  timeout: undefined }
{ [Error: Query inactivity timeout]
  code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
  fatal: true,
  timeout: undefined }
Query inactivity timeout`

I'm not entirely sure where to go next.  I've tried installing my own mysql instance, creating a db and using that - but I get the exact same error.
Any clues much appreciated.  I'm assuming it's a "Stupid User Error" given I'm having an issue with the tutorial :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got to the bottom of this.  There is a regression bug in Node v 4.2.0.

See: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/1236

As per these notes, I've updated to v4.2.1 and it's working fine.
Hopefully this helps someone else.